# Issue with bokeh import

Tags: python, libraries, python-import, bokeh

I installed `bokeh` using `pip` and I am trying to test it but its giving me a `traceback` error to

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/bokeh/properties.py", line 611
    return { self.keys_type.from_json(key, models): self.values_type.from_json(value, models) for key, value in iteritems(json) }
                                                                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bokeh does not support Python 2.6.

Comment: Thats unfortunate. Thanks

Comment: I agree, but it's simply a matter of very finite resources, already spread too thin. If someone submits a PR with necessary changes to support Python 2.6, we could consider it (including adding  it to our CI testing automation to maintain).